# Compile errors with templates and new/delete operators (C++)

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to build a *vector*-style class and in order to use templates as well as the `new`, `delete` operators I have this piece of code:

```
template <class type2> class storage
{
         private:
                 type2 *organs;
         public:
                int num;
                storage(); //constructor
                ~storage(); //destructor
                void operator+(type2 newone);
                void operator-(int howmany);
                type2 operator[](int place);
};


storage<class type2>:: ~storage()
{
          delete[] organs; //~~~~~~~Error number 1~~~~~~~~~~
}

void storage<class type2>:: operator+(type2 newone)
{ //                        ~~~~~~~~~~~Error number 2~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     organs = new type2[1];
     num++;
     oragns[num-1] = newone;
}
```

The compiler (Dev C++) writes this error on Error number 1:

> invalid use of undefined type `struct
>   type2'

And this error on Error Number 2:

> `newone' has incomplete type

However, I don't understand what's wrong. Any hints?

Comment: Read this: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.12

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify what template you are using for those methods or move the function implementation into the class.

```
template <class type2>
storage<class type2>:: ~storage()
{
      delete[] organs;
}
```

Probably the easiest solution.  The same should work for your second error as well.

EDIT:

Found a nice template tutorial which covers this, among other things.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/

Comment: No problem.  I was just doing some template programming this morning, so it was fresh on my mind. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are major bugs in this code aside from the compilation error.

- Totally wrong signature for operator+. You might use operator+= as an append, which presumably is what you are doing. You should probably return a reference to self.
- operator- also perhaps make operator-=
- If operator+ is supposed to append you are not doing so. You are just allocating a new element, losing whatever you had before with no way of recovering it, i.e. that memory has no pointers pointing to it and you cannot delete it.
- As you have a destructor defined you need to handle copying and assignment
- operator[] would ideally have 2 overloads, one const and one non-const. If you do really want to return by value you should probably make it const.